# UITableView position of swipe action when following readable width

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a UITableView which follows readable width. This means that there are very wide margins on an iPad in landscape mode. My cells have swipeable actions. When I swipe left (e.g. to delete the cell), the placements of the actions do not follow the (readable) width of the table view, but are placed at the right edge of the screen. It's functional, but looks really odd.

Is there a way to force the right edge of the swipeable actions to align with the right edge of the (readable width) table view?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you post screenshots?

Comment: See above in original question.